# safe/standard way of casting a c++ object to void*

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there a safe/standard way to assign a object to void * in c++ and then convert it back to the object type later on??

It could be done implicitly:

Example:

```
gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(ptrGUI->CloseButton), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(completeSignalStrengthTest),(gpointer) ptrGUI);
```

Callback:

```
void completeSignalStrengthTest(GtkWidget* myWidget,GdkEvent  *event,gpointer   data)
{
    cout<<"Signal Strength test is completed"<<endl;

    GUI* _ptrGUI = (GUI *)data;
```

it could be done explicitly too using static_cast<>

I have seen this in many places in code, and I am currently debugging a core dump(maybe the problem lies somewhere else), but does it have any effect the way you make use of void* in c++??

Comment: `GUI* _ptrGUI = (GUI *)data;` is not implicit.  C-style casts are explicit, and overly powerful.  Avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.

For casting to `void *` you don't even need to explicitly type it. The other way round (from `void *`) you'd use `static_cast`. If you happen to have a `const` pointer to your object, however, you are going to need `const_cast` as well.

In the code you have written `gpointer`, what is it? is it typedef'd `void *`? If so, it's ok. If not, you can use `reinterpret_cast`.

Anyway, you must be sure you really are passing `GUI *` on only that, in order to avoid runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `reinterpret_cast` can be used to cast from an object to `void*` and back.

Other method would be to use a base class and passing a base class pointer which is then casted back to derived class. (But then its GTK+)

Answer (score -1):

- standard way: Yes, use reinterpret_cast or C style cast
- safe way: No, you can not guarantee that the callee will pass an object of the type you're expecting.

A more common way of doing things in C++ would be to define an interface and virtual methods you access through the base pointer, however in many cases when dealing with legacy or C APIs, you're forced to use pointers and to cast them. If this is the case, be very careful about how you use them.